# Wrong date format being passed over API to backend

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

In my angular + angular material app I have a date range picker where I want to send the users selected start and end date in params overAPI call... my issue is that the date value over API in payload is the whole date with hours, minutes, seconds, time zone, etc... while I want to send only a formated date (example: 2023-09-11)...

I am formating the date but upon clicking apply on my form... the sent date in payload is still the whole thing... why is the datepicker over riding my formated date or is there a mistake in my code?

component.hmtl

```
            <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
              <mat-label>Enter date:</mat-label>
              <mat-date-range-input ngModel [formGroup]="range" [rangePicker]="picker">
                <input matStartDate formControlName="start" placeholder="Start date" >
                <input matEndDate formControlName="end" placeholder="End date">
              </mat-date-range-input>
              <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
              <mat-date-range-picker #picker>
                <mat-date-range-picker-actions>
                  <button mat-button matDateRangePickerCancel>Cancel</button>
                  <button mat-raised-button color="primary" matDateRangePickerApply (click)="getSingleCustomerRangeChartData($event)">Apply</button>
                </mat-date-range-picker-actions>
              </mat-date-range-picker>
            </mat-form-field>
```

component.ts

```
  setDate: any = new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 10);
  range: FormGroup; 

  constructor() {
    this.range = new FormGroup({
      start: new FormControl(this.setDate),
      end: new FormControl(this.setDate),
    })
  }

  getSingleCustomerRangeChartData(event: any) {
    const id = Number(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
    this.customerService.getSingleCustomerRangeChartData(id, this.range.value).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.prodajaChart = data;
        // console.log('Podatki grafa: ', data);
        console.log('Selected dates: ', this.range.value);
      },
      error => {
        console.log('Error', error);
      });
  }
```

service.ts:

```
  getSingleCustomerRangeChartData(id:number, range: any) {
    let queryParams = new HttpParams();

    Object.keys(range).forEach((key) => {
      if (range[key] !== null) {
        queryParams = queryParams.append(key, range[key]);
      }
    });
    console.log(queryParams);
    return this.httpClient.get<typeof prodajaChart>(`${environment.apiUrl}stat/sale/${id}`,{params:queryParams})
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It Looks like now you are formatting only initial date here

```
setDate: any = new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 10);
```

but you need to format selected value in `this.range.value` before sending it to server later too

Comment: how would I do that?